# Does EMGU CV support convertMaps()? Are fixed-point DepthTypes missing?

Tags: vb.net, opencv, emgucv

I'm using Emgu.CV 4.8.1.5350 from NuGet and find that `CvInvoke.Remap()` works well with X & Y map-Mats defined as `DepthType.Cv32F`.

However, when I call `ConvertMaps()` to convert these Mats to fixed-point values, I'm getting an exception at runtime with the message:

`OpenCV: dstm1type == CV_16SC2 || dstm1type == CV_32FC1 || dstm1type == CV_32FC2`

The `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType` Enum doesn't include the values `CV_16SC2`, `CV_32FC1` or `CV_32FC2` so I can't specify them when calling `ConvertMaps()`.

Has anyone successfully used Emgu CV's `ConvertMaps()`? And if so, how?

Here's my code:

```
 Dim BScanToPPIMap_X As New Mat(m_CompositePPIMat.Size, DepthType.Cv32F, 1, XMapHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), m_CompositePPIMat.Width * 4)
 Dim BScanToPPIMap_Y As New Mat(m_CompositePPIMat.Size, DepthType.Cv32F, 1, YMapHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), m_CompositePPIMat.Width * 4)

 m_BScanToPPIMap_X = New Mat(m_CompositePPIMat.Size, DepthType.Cv32S, 1)
 m_BScanToPPIMap_Y = New Mat(m_CompositePPIMat.Size, DepthType.Cv32S, 1)

 CvInvoke.ConvertMaps(BScanToPPIMap_X, BScanToPPIMap_Y, m_BScanToPPIMap_X, m_BScanToPPIMap_Y, DepthType.Default, 1)

 XMapHandle.Free()
 YMapHandle.Free()

 BScanToPPIMap_X.Dispose()
 BScanToPPIMap_Y.Dispose()
```

Per my reply to Dan in the comments, here's the working code:

```
Dim BScanToPPIMap_Y As New Mat(m_CompositePPIMat.Size, DepthType.Cv32F, 1, YMapHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), m_CompositePPIMat.Width * 4)

m_BScanToPPIMap_X = New Mat(m_CompositePPIMat.Size, DepthType.Cv32F, 1)
m_BScanToPPIMap_Y = New Mat(m_CompositePPIMat.Size, DepthType.Cv32F, 1)

CvInvoke.ConvertMaps(BScanToPPIMap_X, BScanToPPIMap_Y, m_BScanToPPIMap_X, m_BScanToPPIMap_Y, DepthType.Cv32F, 1)

XMapHandle.Free()
YMapHandle.Free()

BScanToPPIMap_X.Dispose()
BScanToPPIMap_Y.Dispose()
```

I think my mistake was to assume that ConvertMaps()'s destination type had to be a non-floating point type, or what was the point? :-)

Comment: The EmguCV API differs a little bit from the original C++ API -- it separates the data type specification (such as `CV_16SC2`) into two components -- the base type (that's the `CV_16S` part), and a channel count (the `C2` part). You can already see that in the `Mat` constructor calls as well. Hence `CV_16SC2` would be specified as `DepthType.Cv16S, 2`. `CV_32FC2` would be specified as `DepthType.Cv32F, 2`, and as for `CV_32FC1`, well there doesn't seem to be a need to explain that, since you already did that in your code example...

Comment: Thanks Dan, yes I'd assumed that was the case. Perhaps there's an issue with the way cvinvoke.convertmaps() passes those details onto the underlying implementation. I just wondered if anyone else had seen the same behaviour?

Comment: In your current example, you specify the underlying type to be `DepthType.Default`. I'm not really sure how that's going to be handled, but it doesn't really match what you're asking for in the question. Can you perhaps try some of those things I've mentioned in my comment, and if they still don't work, [edit] your question with more details?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct. As an experiment, I had tried each of the available DepthType values for the dstm1type parameter, including DepthType.Default, to see if the exception message would change at all? So I took your advice and tried again using DepthType.Cv32F and 1 channel in both the Mat definitions and the dstm1type parameter, and it worked! I've added the working code to my question. Thanks for your help - really appreciate it :-)